# Using 通う(かよう) and 通る(とおる)

Tags: meaning, sentence

How can I distinguish the using of both on a sentence? Please, can you give me an example of sentence that use both? Do both have similar meaning?

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55393/what-does-%e9%80%9a%e3%82%8b-mean-in-this-context/55397#55397

Answer (score 3):

`通{かよ}う` means "to commute" and it refers to the act of repeatedly going to and returning from a place. For example,

- `学校に通う途中で` (on my way to commute to a school)
- `病院に通う` (I'm seeing a doctor periodically.)

`通{とお}る` means "to pass" or "to go through" and you should picture some path (say road or tube) and something else moving along it. For example,

- `高速道路を通って一時間` (it'll be one hour by highway)
- `試験に通る` (pass an exam)

Comment: ありがとう。It's very helpfull